# Optimizing the usage of std::vector with other vectors

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I want to know what the most efficient way to set one vector equal to another and free the memory in the first vector after its changed. I can't imagine that resizing a vector to the other one and iterating over it and setting each index is the most efficient way,

```
std::vector< int > a, b;
//Stuff happens

//Swap
b.resize(a.size());
for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++){
    b[i] = a[i];
}

a.clear();
```

I'd imagine something such as `memset` would be much more efficient, or, `emplace_back` when you push elements in without copying or constructing something, but I don't know which one is more efficient or how to use it with `std::vector`'s. There is also `a = b` but what is that doing behind the scenes? Is it copying it, rather than just setting the existing vector `a`'s memory into `b`? What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know what the most efficient way to set one vector equal to another and free the memory in the first vector after its changed.

Simply *move* one `vector` into the other so ownership of the source `vector`'s existing memory gets transferred, while also freeing the existing memory of the target `vector`.

```cpp
b = std::move(a);
```

Though technically, a move assignment `operator=` is *allowed* to just swap the memories of the two `vector`s around, such that `b`'s memory won't get freed until `a` is destroyed at some later time.  Whether or not that actually happens is implementation-dependent.  If you don't want to rely on that, you could do this instead:

```cpp
b = vector<int>(std::move(a));
```

That will move-construct a temporary `vector` that takes ownership of `a`'s memory, and then move-assign that memory onto `b`, and *if* `b::operator=` happens to swap memories then `b`'s old memory will get freed when the temporary `vector` is destroyed, rather than when `a` is destroyed.

> There is also `a = b` but what is that doing behind the scenes? Is it copying it, rather than just setting the existing vector `a`'s memory into `b`?

It makes a *copy* of `a`'s data in `b`, leaving `a` as-is.  Similar to the `resize+iteration` loop you presented (but more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` has a copy-assignment operator, what that means is that you can assign all a `vector`'s values to another `vector`. This means that:

```
b.resize(a.size());
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}
a.clear()
```

is the same as:

```
b = a;
a.clear()
```

So yeah! It is pretty simple!

Hope this helped you!

Comment: This code is using `vector`'s copy-assignment operator, not its copy-constructor

Comment: Thanks! I forgot ;)